# Как сделать так, чтобы у одного из юзеров, были видны изменения других без обновления страницы?

Tags: javascript

Вопрос чисто концептуальный. Понятно, что, чтобы получить актуальный данные нужно сделать запрос, к примеру, обновить страницу или нажать на кнопку. Но как получить актуальные данные от сервера, которые обновляются очень часто(например, пользователь зашел в сеть)? Делать запрос постоянно??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы ищите - это сокеты.

https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket

Используйте для задач с интерактивным общением пользователя с сервером или другими пользователями real-time engines например - https://socket.io/ для node.js

Вот небольшой пример его использования для создания чата:
https://habr.com/ru/post/307744/

Comment: Благодарю! Как раз интересовался Socket.io!)